# Cannot INSERT data in table which has a foreign key

Tags: python, sql, tkinter, insert

I want to insert data in table Committed Crimes but it calls an error. The data which I want to insert is already added to other tables. For example, The table Criminals has a value 1 (Criminal_ID) and table Laws has a value 3 (Law_ID). When I insert in committed crimes these data, it calls an error. Do you know why and how it can be solved?

[image]

```
from tkinter import *
import pypyodbc
import ctypes

#Create connection
con = pypyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};UID=admin;UserCommitSync=Yes;Threads=3;SafeTransactions=0;PageTimeout=5;MaxScanRows=8;MaxBufferSize=2048;FIL={MS Access};DriverId=25;DefaultDir=C:/Users/HP/Desktop/PITL;DBQ=C:/Users/HP/Desktop/PITL/PITL.mdb;')
cursor = con.cursor ()

form=Tk ()
form.title ("Add data")
form.geometry ('400x200')

a = Entry (form, width=10, font="Arial 16")
a.pack()
b = Entry (form, width=10, font="Arial 16")
b.pack()

def Add ():
    cursor.execute ("INSERT INTO Committed crimes (`Criminal_ID`, `Law_ID`) VALUES (?, ?)", (a.get(), b.get()))
    con.commit ()

Button=Button(form, text = 'PUSH ME', command = Add)
Button.pack()

form.mainloop ()
cursor.close ()
con.close ()
```

Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)   File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\PITL\ADD DATA.py", line 19, in Add
    cursor.execute ("INSERT INTO Committed crimes (`Criminal_ID`, `Law_ID`) VALUES (?, ?)", (a.get(), b.get()))   File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc-1.3.4-py3.6.egg\pypyodbc.py", line 1617, in execute
    check_success(self, ret)   File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc-1.3.4-py3.6.egg\pypyodbc.py", line 1007, in check_success
    ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, ODBC_obj.stmt_h, ret, ODBC_obj.ansi)   File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc-1.3.4-py3.6.egg\pypyodbc.py", line 975, in ctrl_err
    raise ProgrammingError(state,err_text) pypyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][Драйвер ODBC Microsoft Access] Ошибка синтаксиса в инструкции INSERT INTO.')
```

Comment: Commited crimes contains a space between the two words.

Comment: which a space is ok to have between the words, you just need to put [] (brackets) around Committed Crimes and should work fine.